# Using OR in htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess

Following URL should be redirected:

```
abc-deut.html -> de/abc
abc-eng.html -> en/abc

Where deut = de
And eng = en
```

I am looking for something like:

```
RewriteRule ^abc-(deut|eng).html (de|en)/abc [R=301,L]
```

Does this work with htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)-(en|de).*\.html$ /$2/$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this don't work, since:
Where deut = de
And eng = en
deut and eng should also be redirected to de and en

Comment: It is redirecting `/abc-deut.html` to `/de/abc` and `/abc-eng.html` to `/en/abc`. What URL is not working for you?

Comment: Exactly. /abc-deut.html should redirect to /de/abc and abc-eng.html to /en/abc

Comment: Yes but is already happening with my rule. Make sure you have it as your first rule. If it doesn't work then post your complete .htaccess in question.